# how to turn a png file into Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, png, uint8array

I acquire an image from the deckstop using an input from html code. Then I would like the photo to be passed to a javascript function to be converted to Uint8Array. how do I do it?

I have implemented only the acquisition in the following way

```
         <input type="file" name="myimage">
```

Comment: What do you want this Uint8Array to represent? The binary file or ImageData?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file as an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)'s `FileReader` object and its [`readAsArrayBuffer` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer), and then use that `ArrayBuffer` to create a [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array). Roughly:

```
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = () => {
    // It worked
    const array = new Uint8Array(fr.result);
    // ...use the array here...
};
fr.onerror = () => {
    // The read failed, handle/report it
};
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(yourInputElement.files[0]);
```

Here's a quick and dirty example: If you select a file, this will tell you whether it's a PNG file or some other kind of file by looking in the data for the PNG header:

```js
const PNG_HEADER = Uint8Array.of(0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A);
document.getElementById("yourInput").addEventListener("change", function() {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    const file = this.files[0];
    let {name} = file;
    const x = name.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (x !== -1) {
        name = name.substring(x + 1);
    }
    fr.onload = () => {
        // It worked
        const array = new Uint8Array(fr.result);
        if (array.length >= PNG_HEADER.length &&
            PNG_HEADER.every((byte, index) => byte === array[index])) {
            console.log(`${name} is a PNG`);
        } else {
            console.log(`${name} is not a PNG`);
        }
    };
    fr.onerror = () => {
        // The read failed, handle/report it
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="yourInput">
```

Comment: array will count the binary values of the image?

Comment: @VINCENZOBOVINO - The array will contain the bytes of the image. I've added an example that uses the bytes (in this example, to check if the file is a PNG or some other kind of file).

Comment: if I wanted to transform more files taken from the folder where the web pages are?

Comment: @VINCENZOBOVINO - That's a completely different question, and would need much more detail to be answerable. (And is probably already answered on SO somewhere.)

Comment: you could help me, I really need it.